# Extract the data Using regular Expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have the unproper data in this way. i need to extract the data before dot and after dot symbol using regular expression. I am using  but i am not able to get exact data. please help. It is very urgent

Code:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([\\w[\\$#@\\-^&]\\w\\[\\]' $]+)\\.([\\w\\[\\]' $]+)").matcher(formulaData);
while (matcher.find()) 
{
String Data=matcher.group(0);
String[] pieces = Data.split("\\.");
Heading=pieces[0].replace("\"", "");
Heading=pieces[1].replace("\"", "");

 }//while
```

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are looking for. Give examples of the data before and after.

Comment: I updated the output .. please check it once

Comment: HI Michael, I updated the code please check it once

Answer (score 0):

You can split by newline and then split by dot

Comment: yes we can split the data .. but in that data we have even sql queries

Comment: Try this pattern: "\"\\w[\\s\\w]+\"\\.\"\\w[\\s\\w]+\""; The output produced in your code is :                                                                                   Table: Disti Partner , column: Disti Parent Name
Table: Bookings Adjusted , column: ELA Indicator
Table: Bookings Adjusted , column: ELA Cap
Table: Partner Program , column: Program Tier
Table: Partner Program , column: Program Tier